# Include files R?

Tags: r

Is it possible to use include files in R like in most programming languages, for example C?

Comment: Be careful with variable name clobbering!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use `source` and/or `sys.source`.

Comment: As in: `source(file="filename.r")` or simply `source("filename.r")`

Comment: Note that source() executes the commands in the specified file, it does not (like PHP include) simply paste the contents of that file into the including file.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the location of the file will then need to be hard-coded, which doesn't work when developing packages. I tried the following bit of magic to work out the location of the current R script, relative to which the location of the include file can be worked out. It works on its own, but doesn't when the code is turned into a package: `frame_files <- lapply(sys.frames(), function(x) x$ofile);  frame_files <- Filter(Negate(is.null), frame_files); PATH <- dirname(frame_files[[length(frame_files)]])`

Comment: @Contango How does one paste contents like in PHP, then?

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, including notes:

Doing this will execute the commands in the file, so be careful with it.

```
source("my_file.r")
```

or

```
source(file="my_file.r")
```