# how to do R includes

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Include files R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502925/include-files-r)

I cannot find useful documentation about an R file including another R file. R is a very short word is ignored by search engines.

I have file.R and include.R and I want to do something like this:

```
// in include.R I want to load libraries
library(phpSerialize)

// in file.R include the previous file and use directly the given library
include(include.R)

x = rnorm(10)
y =  phpSerialize(x)
```

Comment: (1) www.rseek.org is really good at finding R content and (2) is `source()` the command you need?

Comment: Or if you only need the data/results, and not the functions, then `save.image()` and `load()` may do the trick. `source()` will run the entire script, which could be time consuming if you only need the data/results.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Include files R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502925/include-files-r)

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich it is .. but as I was saying search is difficult and I could not find it.

Comment: @Elzo Valugi I understand searching for R answers can be difficult, especially via Google, Yahoo, Bing, etc.  If you had searched stackoverflow for "[r] include" (which is all I did), the question I linked to is the first result.  Nothing personal.  Cheers.

Comment: I did not knew about this way of search. I do now. Thanks. I voted for closing.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Maybe you are just looking for `source(file="include.R")`. Note that `source()` executes the commands in the specified file, it does not (like PHP include) simply paste the contents of that file into the including file. Which is probably not important in your case.

Comment: maybe. I hope so. Multam fain.

Comment: This is useful when you have a function (or several of them) in specific files. You just run source on that filename and you've got the functions locked and loaded.

Comment: So, how can I actually paste the content of an external file like "include" in php? In my case, the output statements in the external file are ignored when I simply put it in "source".

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `source`, you may be interested in `sys.source`.  It gives you more control over the environment the file is evaluated in.