# how to replace letters of batch of files in Linux

Tags: linux, r, terminal, vi

Suppose I have a dictionary `/home/program/`. And there are 5 programs (`program_1.R,program_2.R,program_3.R,program_4.R,program_5.R`). And each of five programs has "`rep=100`"   in their files. Now I want to change "`rep=100`" as "`rep=500`" in each file. I always change it one by one. Is there a simpler to do that?

Comment: I would suggest to include some config.R where you set "rep=500". IMO it would work better.

Comment: See this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502925/include-files-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so you ask for a shell script to change all your files in one step, right?
Then try this one:

```
find /home/program -name "*.R" -type f -exec sed -i 's/rep=100/rep=500/g' {} \;
```

Having multiple directories (you mean directories - not "dictionaries"?!), you can build a loop around the find-command:

```
for d in /home/program1 /home/program2 /home/program3; do
  find "$d" -name "*.R" -type f -exec sed -i 's/rep=100/rep=500/g' {} \;
done
```

Please, have a look at `man find` and `man sed` to understand the respective program-options.

Comment: Thank you! When I have multiple dictionaries under `home`, for example `/home/program1`,`/home/program2`. And each of dictionary of `program1` and `program2` has several programs. I want to replace all of them. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple for loop

```
for i in `ls program_*`;do sed -i 's/rep=100/rep=500/g' $i;done
```